# How can I stage additional files using Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am reading a bunch configuration files in my Google Dataflow program and wonder what is the best way to stage them. Currently I do it this way and the system cannot find them.

```
FileReader filereader1 = new FileReader("config_1.csv");
FileReader filereader2 = new FileReader("config_2.csv");
```

`config_1.csv` and `config_2.csv` are stored in `./target/classes/org/model/examples/`

My running script looks like this:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.model.examples.MyPipeline \
-Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner \
    --project=mortgage-data-warehouse
    --gcpTempLocation=gs://my-project-bucket/tmp \
    --inputFile=gs://my-project-bucket/Data/input.txt \
    --filesToStage=./target/classes/org/datamodel/examples/config_1.csv, ./target/classes/org/datamodel/examples/config_2.csv" \    
-Pdataflow-runner
```

I have got the error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: config_1.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)

I wonder if this is the proper way to set `--filesToStage`.

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace from the error? Do you get the `FileNotFoundException` on your local machine when submitting the job, or inside the Dataflow job when attempting to read the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small configuration files, it is better to read files from resource folder such as what has been written by this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) and avoid the complication of using `--filesToStage`