# include other files with dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My dataflow uses a **.sql** file. This file contains a query and it sits in a directory called `queries`.

I need to have this file uploaded with my dataflow.

What I found was the use of a manifest.in file but that does not do anything as far as I can see, I've made this file called `MANIFEST.in` in my root directory and it contains a single line:

`recursive-include queries *`

Some other sources tell me I need to use the **setup.py** file for this. So now it looks like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

import subprocess
from distutils.command.build import build as _build

import setuptools  # pylint: disable-all
setuptools.setup(
    name='MarkPackage',
    version='0.0.1',
    install_requires=[],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'queries': ['queries/*'],
    },
    include_package_data=True
)
```

This also does not work.
The error is: `RuntimeError: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'queries/testquery.sql' [while running 'generatedPtransform-20']`

What is the best practise to include any file to use in any or all parts of my dataflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution was brought to me by our Google Cloud consultant. It worked but it is advised against because it add complexity just for separating the SQL query from the Python code.
An alternative would be to make a View on Bigquery containing this SQL code and maintain it there in the Bigquery environment.

**MANIFEST.in**
`include query.sql`

**setup.py**

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name="example",
    version="0.0.1",
    install_requires=[],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    data_files=[(".", ["query.sql"])],
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

**main.py**

```
with open ("query.sql", "r") as myfile:
        query=myfile.read()
    with beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args) as p:
        rows = p | "ReadFromBQ" >> beam.io.Read(
            beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True)
        )
        rows | "writeToBQ" >> beam.io.Write(
            "BQ Write"
            >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                known_args.output_table,
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            )
        )
```

Comment: `data_files` is the key

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're doing with the file you want to include, but considering this is a SQL file (and not a local Python package or Non-Python dependency) one way of "including" it is by putting it in a Google Cloud Storage bucket and adding it as a argument:

```py
def run(argv=None): 
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--input',
        dest='input',
        default='gs://bucket/queries/query.sql',
        help='Input SQL file.'
        )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_args.extend([
          '--runner=DataflowRunner',
          '--project=proj',
          '--region=region',
          '--staging_location=gs://bucket/staging/',
          '--temp_location=gs://bucket/temp/',
          '--job_name=name',
          '--setup_file=./setup.py'
          ])
```

Now if you need to use this file as a parameter in a `PTransform`, you can pass `known_args.input` into it. Hope this helps

Comment: This works perfectly for a text file I need to parse line-by-line, but I'm not exactly sure how you are using the SQL file so maybe passing it as a parameter to a `PTransform` doesn't fit your use-case.

Comment: This is a pretty smart solution (upvoted) but I think there must be a more simple one that does not entail adding a service component (storage).

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using filesToStage, following the pattern described in this [existing SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516965/staging-files-on-google-dataflow-worker). This will allow you to provide a file. There are some "gotchas" to this approach, so please review the answer carefully.

Unfortunately the [simplest solution I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124906/how-can-i-stage-additional-files-using-google-cloud-dataflow) is a java specific solution. Using a resource folder to package config files into the jar. Then using java provided APIs to read the file back out.