# Adding a JSON data file to GCP Dataflow package and using it inside the code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, manifest, setup.py, dataflow

I want to add a JSON file to my Dataflow (Apache Beam) package and use it inside the code.

I've seen several questions on Stack Overflow with different answers, and I tried the [recommended approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159615/include-other-files-with-dataflow) with a `MANIFEST.in` and adding `data_files` to the `setup.py` file. But nothing I tried works for me.

Here is my current setup.

[image: File Structure]

(I have `mapping.json` in both the common folder and the root folder for testing purposes.)

**MANIFEST.in**

```
recursive-include common *.json
```

**setup.py**

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    data_files=[
                    ("common", ["mapping.json"])
                ],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'apache-beam[gcp]==2.31.0',
        'python-dateutil==2.8.1'
    ],
 )
```

**Using the file inside `common/config.py`**

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path


def _load_category_theme_mapping(file_name):
    path = Path(__file__).parent / file_name
    with path.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        return json.load(file)

mapping = _load_category_theme_mapping("mapping.json")
```

I'm using Flex Templates to run my Dataflow job and I copy the `common` folder to the target `common` folder.

When I run the Dataflow job with this setup, it just throws an error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/common/category_theme_mapping.json'
```

I tried moving the `.json` file outside of the `common` folder (into the root folder) and changed the code (and the Dockerfile) accordingly to read from the base folder.

Then I changed the `setup.py` file to have the `data_files` to `(".", ["mapping.json"]` and `MANIFEST.in` to have `include *.json`, but it still fails.

I also tried without having a `MANIFEST.in`, but then the launcher fails without any informative log.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error throws a file not found, this means that when you are mapping it searches for a different file, one possible solution to this is to change your file name to `category_theme_mapping.json` since that is the file that the mapping is searching for.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake from my end while making a generic sample. But it failed saying it didn't find `mapping.json` :|