# Import values from a Pcollection

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow

Currently I´m developing a process where I take some values from a Pcollection but I need to get  a query with the parameters that it receives.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from pydantic import fields
from ..tools import ProcessLogger
from google.cloud import bigquery
_logger = ProcessLogger()
class ConcatFieldsFn(beam.DoFn):
    """Concatena los valores de los campos especificados en una pCollection por un valor especificado"""

    def __init__(self, process: str, data_name: str, parameters: dict):
        # Configuracion del logger
        self.logger_data_name = data_name
        self.logger_process = process
        self.logger_subprocess = "Concatenar valores"
        _logger.data_name = self.logger_data_name
        _logger.process = self.logger_process
        _logger.subprocess = self.logger_subprocess

        # Parametros del proceso
        self._fields = [field.get("name") for field in parameters.get("fields", None)]
        

        bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

        das = f"SELECT CONCAT({self._fields}) FROM `bic-dev.gf_comercial_bic_dev_datacruda_bq.m_{self.logger_data_name}`".replace("]", "").replace("[", "").replace("'", "").replace(",",",'-',")
        query_job = bigquery_client.query(das)
        results = query_job.result() 
        
        _logger.info(
            f"Se aplica regla: {_logger.subprocess} con los parametros: {parameters}"
        )            
        
           





    def process(self, element):
        # Configuracion del logger
        _logger.data_name = self.logger_data_name
        _logger.process = self.logger_process
        _logger.subprocess = self.logger_subprocess

        for field in self._fields:
            if element[field] != None:
                try:
                    element[field] = ",".join(element[field])
                except Exception as ex:
                    _logger.error(ex)

        return [element]
```

it´s the code and I need to import in other file "das" that contains a query.

How can I do it. Thanks

Comment: If you want to import it as a Python file, just create a Python file with the query as an f-string and simply import it as usual. If you want to add it as a text file (or any file format other than .py), you have to add the file to the package. 
If you're using Flex templates, then you need to add it to the `setup.py` file. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159615/include-other-files-with-dataflow) question. For classic templates, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I am connecting a result that  is an output from apache beam and it returns some parameters and executes the query, but I know how to get that query with those parameters to take it to another file

Comment: What do you mean "another file"? I'm not sure if this helps, but please take a look into a [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/) for DoFns. It helps you to pass Python data structures (non-pCollections) to transforms.